# how do i make a form select option php mysql loop and have the correct option selected in 3 different scenarios?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

so let's say i have this dropdown box loop which is populated via database table.  by the way this is on an edit/update form page, not the initial create/insert form page.

```
<select name="company" id="company">
<option value="">-select-</option>
<?php
$selectedvendor = $row['company'];
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row1['company'] ?>"
<?php
if (count($_POST)>0) {
    if ($row1['company'] == $_POST["company"]) {
        echo " selected='selected'";
    }
} else {
    if ($row1['company'] == $selectedvendor) {
        echo " selected='selected'";
    }
}
?>
><?php echo $row1['company'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

i am trying to make it so that the correct option is selected in 3 different scenarios.

scenario 1: on initial page load

scenario 2: form was submitted but validation of some fields failed

scenario 3: form was submitted and there were no validation errors and form submitted successfully

right now, with the above code, scenario 1 and 2 work.  i need to know how to make scenario 3 work.

whichever option was selected which saved to the database, that is the one that should be selected.

Comment: If option 2 works perfectly then you don't need to worry about option 3 because when form is saved then it means post value is equal to the value saved in db and when op loads page then your option 1 will take care to show the right selected value which is already working as you stated

Comment: you're right, i didn't test enough.  i didn't have this configuration of code before, and when i finally made it this way i assumed it was still wrong.

Comment: But one thing i want to say that you should always check the submitted value,it should be one from the dropdown options you have provided to the user so this way you don't have any bot actions like if i change the value from the dom elements like using firebug other than the value from dropdown then it should not go to database